# Netezza replace blank with underscore

Tags: netezza

In Netezza, is there a way to replace  blanks in a string with a single underscore?
i.e 'A    BC D' --> 'A_BC_D'

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace each blank in the source string with an underscore you can use the standard TRANSLATE function.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select translate('A BC D',' ','_');
 TRANSLATE
-----------
 A_BC_D
(1 row)
```

If you want to do something like replace all strings of contiguous whitespace with a single underscore you might want to use the regexp functions in the SQL Toolkit.  Here I happen to have the SQL Toolkit functions installed in a database called SQLEXT.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select sqlext..regexp_replace('A BC     D','\s+','_');
 REGEXP_REPLACE
----------------
 A_BC_D
(1 row)
```